# appending a string to a list of strings if the string in the list is equal to some variable in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
a=['item1', 'item2', 'item3', ...]
b='item2'
```

now if I want to say add * to the beginning and end of 'item2' in the list 'a' how can i do that?

Comment: (1) find index of `'item2'` in the list; (2) assign `'*item2*'` to that index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a **[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**:

```
>>> a = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
>>> b = 'item2'
>>> c = [f'*{s}*' if s == b else s for s in a]
>>> c
['item1', '*item2*', 'item3']
```